# Does Varnish Cache conflict with wordpress cache plugins?

Tags: caching

I've noticed recently that I have Varnish Cache activated on my host with bluehost, the question is what is Varnish Cache exactly, how does it differ from cache using wordpress plugins (W3 Total cache for example) - and most importantly - do they conflict working together?

Comment: check the website https://varnish-cache.org/, it has a nice video introduction :)

Comment: as for the plugins hmm I think they are application caching solutions not http caching solutions, the difference lies on where does the cache sit and what does it cache, I don't think they'll conflict but having both may cause memory issues